# ulimit soft limit for file descriptors - for a non-root user on CentOS 5.6

Tags: centos, reboot, root, ulimit, file-descriptors

I am needing to increase the soft limit for "file descriptors", and make it effective for a non-root user (lets say user1).

Ran these commands, while logged in as user1:

```
>ulimit -a

    core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
    data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
    scheduling priority             (-e) 0
    file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
    pending signals                 (-i) 61440
    max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
    max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
    open files                      (-n) 1024
    pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
    POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
    real-time priority              (-r) 0
    stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
    cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
    max user processes              (-u) 61440
    virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
    file locks                      (-x) unlimited


> ulimit -Hc
unlimited

> ulimit -n unlimited
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

user1 is not on the sudoers list. is this command effective, only when run as a root user?

Also, does this change require a server reboot, to become effective?

Answer (score 0):

> user1 is not on the sudoers list. is this command effective, only when run as a root user?

Increases can only be done by root. Reductions can be done by anyone. You need an increase, so need to be root.

> Also, does this change require a server reboot, to become effective?

No, but you may want a new process, or new shell.

Comment: Thank you. i am going to get root access and try this out.